# Obtain data from internet with jsoup

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

**hi, i was trying obtain data from a page but i don't know how to obtain this data: **Chapter 120** and de url link

This is the code from page (i simplified it):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="card chapters" id="chapters">
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
<li class="list-group-item p-0 bg-light upload-link" data-index="0">
<h4 class="px-2 py-3 m-0">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-10 text-truncate">
<a style="display: block;" class="btn-collapse" onclick="collapseChapter('collapsible490362')" role="button"> Capítulo 120.00</a>
</div>
</div>
</h4>
<div style="display: block;" id="collapsible490362">
<div class="card chapter-list-element">
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush chapter-list">
<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-2 col-sm-1 text-right">
<a href="https://lectortmo.com/view_uploads/599487" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<span class="fas fa-play fa-2x" style="color:#2957ba"></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In this line we can see the text **(Chapter 120)** that i need show in `TextView` but i don't know how to obtain it

```
<a style="display: block;" class="btn-collapse" onclick="collapseChapter('collapsible490362')" role="button"> Chapter 120</a>
```

And in this line we can see the url that i need:

```
<a href="https://lectortmo.com/view_uploads/599487" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
```

This is my method to obtain data parsing:

```
@Override
    protected ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");

        tmoDatosSeleccions.clear();
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("div.row>.col-10");
            int size = data.size();
            Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
            Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
            Log.d("size", ""+size);
            for (Element e : data) {
                String numeroCap = e.select("a").attr("none");
                String urlManga = e.select("div.row>.col-2").select("a").addClass("btn").attr("href").trim();
                tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlManga));
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmoDatosSeleccions;
    }
```

Someone can help me?

Print Screen:

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to show what is output by the Log.d lines?

Comment: Yes, i was updated the code with a screen @Spuggiehawk

Comment: Hmm.  The line that you're getting into your "data" variable is only the single line of HTML that includes the col-10 class.  After you've got that line, your code looks like it's expecting children of that div to include the col-2 class, but that is in a separate block.
If you only want the link, you could use:
... = doc.select("div.row>.col-10 a")
or
... = doc.select("div.row>.col-2 a")  if you only really want the col-2 link.

ie. no need to loop through elements, just access them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the two links you are trying to find using:

```
Elements data = doc.select("div.row a");
for (Element e : data)
{
    // process the link
}
```

Or you could get them individually using:

```
Elements data = doc.select("div.row>.col-10 a");
if (data.size() == 1)
{
    Element e = data.get(0);
    // process col-10 link
}

data = doc.select("div.row>.col-2 a");
if (data.size() == 1)
{
    Element e = data.get(0);
    // process col-2 link
}
```

The main problem you were having was that the col-2 element was not nested inside the col-10 element, so your loop would not have found any items.

Comment: Well, i can solve my problem to obtain data with another method but thank you it was thank to your answer that i can solve it